# overflow-x: auto not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML code:

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.table-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  _overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class='table-container'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Example</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the `overflow-x: auto` is not working because of `display: table` in main container. I need to keep the `display: table` property because I want the container div width the same as the content inside it. How to keep overflow-y working using display: table in main container?

Comment: add the height in table container.

Comment: @Fiido93 I want a horizontal scroll.

Comment: You say overflow y isnt working..  and now u want horizontal scroll lol, then add the width in table container. in your parent div you already set the 100% that why it doesnt working.

Comment: @Fiido93 I'm doing this for mobile table adaptation. I want the user swipe to left to see the content of the table. If I remove the display: table this works as desidered. But I need to use display: table and get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?

EDIT: I think your problem is the height. You have to manually specify it depending on your content. If you know what the content is you can specify it, if not you have to use javascript

```css
    .container {
        display: table;
        width : 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .table-container {
        position : absolute;
        left: 0;
        right:0;
        overflow-y: auto;

    }
    #scroller{
        height:100px;
       
    }
```

```html
<div class='container' id="scroller">
    <div class='table-container'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Example</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."


    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you need it to behave?

Comment: Like that: http://maxdesign.com.au/jobs/example-table/index1.htm
Please resize the window and see the scroll.

Comment: @M.Victor remove that display table on your container.

Comment: The answer above does what the example does. Click on run Code snippet, then do view full screen.

Comment: @Fiido93 But I need it because I want the container div width the same as the content inside it. I don't know another method to actieve this that isn't using display: table.

Comment: @M.Victor Have you tried viewing the code in another page?

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working, I just tried it on 3 browsers and it works.

Comment: Actually can you post the code to your page containers? That might be it

Comment: maybe he wanted the table full width same as the container

Comment: and there is overlapping when full screen  @brianxautumn :D

Comment: Its probably the height. If you want the relative div to wrap to the height of an absolute one inside you have to manually set it.